# Show/hide divs on click, but prevent the script from executing if same link is clicked a second time

Tags: jquery, click, show-hide

The script works fine when clicking on any of the links. I want it to prevent the show/hide script from executing if the same link is clicked a second time. I have found a few things on this site and others to try with .unbind being the most promising, but my the function starts with `$(this).click(function ()`, and unbinding kills everything. I cannot figure out a way to restructure the code so it checks `toggleDiv` before the click against `toggleDiv` after the click to see if they are the same and removes the scripts.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/jpscoggan/pen/gcHbK

Here is my js code:

```
//show hide
(function ($) {

    $.fn.showHide = function (options) {

        //default vars for the plugin
        var defaults = {
            speed: 200,
            easing: 'swing'
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $(this).click(function () {
            $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);
            // once the button is clicked, the clicked div (.toggleDiv) slides up  
            var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
            // reads rel attribute of clicked link / which div id to toggle 
            $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing);
            // toggle show/hide the correct div + speed and easing

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.show_hide').showHide({
    speed: 200,
    // speed you want the toggle to happen             
});
```

Comment: Use the one() function: `$(this).one('click', function() {});` this will only run once

Comment: I tried using .one, but I want users to be able to click as many times as they like, just not on the same link consecutively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to go about this: add a class to the one you just clicked, and then disallow a second click if that link is active.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ofrEG)

```
$('.show_hide section').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
    //use if you want to allow a click after switching sections
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery.one(); function. This function's callback is only reached once and is automatically removed after the call:

```
$(this).one('click', clickHandlerFunction);
```